# how to avoid ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed exception inside Intelij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In terminal, app run fine, but via IntelliJ IDEA I get this exception

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to

how to config Intelij by valid certificate?

Comment: Do you use exactly the same JDK installation for running the app in Terminal and in the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my fault. I had configured `cacert` file in `Java/JRE/` root, that should be
configured into `java/JDK/jre` root.